# Getting Firebase not found error while deploying functions in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to host a app in firebase and its giving me error that

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

I have executed `npm install` command several times but nothing new.

[image]

Please help

Comment: Did you install the Firebase CLI? If you did, make sure you have the updated version. You can run `npm install -g firebase-tools` in your project directory

Comment: Yes i have done that

Comment: It looks like you forgot to run `npm install` (or `npm install firebase`) before deploying. See the last line of the terminal.

Comment: Also, make sure you're running `npm install` from the `functions` subdirectory of your project.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I have done that several times

Answer (score 65):

Cannot find module 'firebase-functions' means that you need to install packages.
In your project directory run

```
$ cd functions
$ npm install
```

then return back and fire!

```
$ firebase deploy
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Still works! Appreciate it

Answer (score 16):

By default, the `firebase` dependency isn't in your `functions/package.json`. Instead, you'll find it lists [`firebase-admin`, the specialized server-side Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) which is the one we recommend using.

If you really do want to use the `firebase` client-side SDK instead of `firebase-admin`, you'll want to run `npm install --save firebase` in your `functions/` directory. You should then have a line in your `functions/package.json` that looks a bit like this:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^3.7.2",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: In my case, following the procedure above, the `package.json` did get updated with `firebase` dependency but I'm still getting the error: `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase' or its corresponding type declarations` when I run `firebase deploy`. Can you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Although this is coming late, but it's for those who might face the same issue. This worked for me. I added this to my package.json file in folder function.

```
 {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.6.2",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mkdirp-promise": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Then run: npm install in folder function

Comment: @jason I'm happy it does. :)

Answer (score 4):

Clean up node_modules,

```
rm -rf package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
```

Update `functions/package.json` file with latest or compatible versions of dependencies with your node version and run `npm install` from functions folder.

Try `firebase deploy` now. Should be good!

Comment: forgetting to do a clean up first was the problem for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, some of the cached packages were installed with root permission. So when I tried to deploy with only `npm run deploy` , was not finding the packages.

`sudo npm run deploy` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to select command prompt terminal instead of power shell ,then install npm within functions then run command npm start .